# What does nondegenerate means for quadratic forms?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

If you have a quadratic form 
$f(X_1,...,X_n)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{i,j}X_iX_j$ or $f(X_1,...,X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i^2$ 
over a field K, how do you define "nondegenerate"?

I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondegenerate_form, but I dont know how to understand it in this situation.

(I'm working with K=$\mathbb{Q}_p$ and K=$\mathbb{Q}$)

Answer (score 1):

A precise definition is given in the wikipedia link on (non-degenerate) [quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form). Since both your fields $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ have characteristic zero, you can always
write $f(x)=x^TAx$ with a symmetric matrix $A$, which can be even transformed into a diagonal matrix $D$. Indeed, the last step fails for fields of characteristic $2$, but this is not your concern. Then $f$ is non-degenerate if and only if all diagonal elements of $D$ are non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

As long as $2$ is invertible, there is a unique symmetric matrix $A$ such that
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\pmatrix{x_1&\cdots&x_n}A\pmatrix{x_1\\\vdots\\x_n}.$$
The quadratic form is nondegenerate iff $A$ is nonsingular.